# Getting issue while fetching prev/next post from Sanity CMS ( Next js +Sanity static blog)

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

I'm using Sanity CMS, and trying to fetch previous and next post using this query below.

```
  const query = `*[_type=='post' && slug.current == $slug][0]{
    _id,title,_updatedAt,
    "newPost" : *[_type == 'post' && ^._updatedAt > _updatedAt][0] {
     title,"slug" : slug.current
   }
}`;
  const param = {
    slug: "some-random-slug",
  };
  const nextPrev = await client.fetch(query, param);
```

My problem is that when I tried this above query at Sanity Vision, it works perfectly. But while trying this with sanity client, it doesn't return the newPost object. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const query = `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0] {
  "nextPost": *[_type == "post" && ^._createdAt < _createdAt] | order(_createdAt asc)[0] {
   // Fields
  }
}`

const { nextPost } = await client.fetch(query, { slug })
```